# error: A doesn't name a type

Tags: c++, class, object

i have created two classes A and B so i have 5 files , main.cpp , A.h , A.cpp , B.h , B.cpp

i have included all headers as it should be and im trying to create a object of class A in class B and i get the following error : error: A doesn't name a type

and if i to it repeated like i define object B in class A it works ,,, whats wrong?

this is how my B.h looks like >

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"

using namespace std;
class B
{
    public:
        B();
    protected:
    private:
        A instance;

};

#endif // B_H
```

and now A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <iostream>
#include "B.h"

using namespace std;
class A
{
    public:
        A();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // A_H
```

Comment: Why are you including `B.H` in `B.H`?

Comment: sorry didnot notice that i just copy pasted all , nvm im gona edit it , but it doesnot change anything

Comment: Things to check: 1. the guard in the other file (is it `#ifndef B_H` too?), 2. the other file including this one.

Comment: You haven't shown `A.h`. My educated guess would be, you have circuclar includes: `A.h` includes `B.h` and `B.h` includes `A.h`

Comment: Perhaps read up on forward declarations might help you

Comment: In A.H why include B.H - You are not using B in that header file

Answer (score 2):

Your `B.h` includes `A.h` and `A.h` includes `B.h`. This leads you to something like `B.h` includes `B.h`.

From `A.h` delete the `include "B.h"`. It is unused.

Comment: @TheBestBoss, if any answer solved your problem, click the gray tick under the score to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at A.h:

First it includes B.h. This pulls in the definition of class B, which uses class A. Next it defines class A. There's the problem. As others have stated removing the unused include will fix the problem.

Comment: look at the example above your comment what wrong there?